# Oracle Spatial query gives ORA-01427 (Single-row Subquery Returns More Than One Row)

Tags: oracle, spatial, spatial-query, oracle-spatial

I'm creating a polygon on a map and trying to fetch the most related street to that polygon. However, while my query works when the polygon covers 3-5 streets, it returns the mentioned error when it covers a larger area. I seek to obtain at least one street code result from my query. What am I missing?

```
SELECT ID FROM STREET WHERE CITY_STREET_CODE = (
    SELECT 
         NS.CITY_STREET_CODE          CITYSTREETCODE
    FROM NEIGHBOURHOOD_STREET NS
    INNER JOIN NEIGHBOURHOOD N
      ON N.ID = NS.NEIGHBOURHOOD_ID
    WHERE SDO_RELATE(N.GEOLOC,
                    MYGEOLOC,
                    'MASK=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE'
     AND NS.CITY_STREET_CODE IN
         (SELECT CITY_STREET_CODE
            FROM (SELECT CITY_STREET_CODE, DISTANCE
                    FROM (SELECT
                           A.CITY_STREET_CODE, SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) DISTANCE
                            FROM STREET A
                           WHERE SDO_NN(A.GEOLOC,
                                        MYGEOLOC,
                                        'SDO_BATCH_SIZE=10 DISTANCE=500 UNIT=M',
                                        1) = 'TRUE'
                             AND A.CITY_STREET_CODE > 0
                           ORDER BY DISTANCE)
                   WHERE ROWNUM <= 1))
                   )
```

ps: I tried lowering and increasing the batch size, I also tried putting "sdo_num_res" instead of it; both didn't work, or its me who couldn't do it properly.

Comment: Change the first `=` to `in`.

Comment: holy meow, thank you good sir! can you post it as a response so I can mark it? (but with a little bit of explanation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with spatial extensions.  The issue is a simple SQL issue.  You have:

```
WHERE CITY_STREET_CODE = ( . . . )
```

However, the subquery can return more than one row -- hence the error.

The simplest solution is to change the `=` to `IN`:

```
WHERE CITY_STREET_CODE IN ( . . . )
```

Comment: thank you once more. the thing I don't get is that I am limiting the result set size with "ROWNUM <= 1", isn't it supposed to return only one result at most in any occasion?

Comment: @AlpA. . . . You are doing that in a sub-subquery.  The condition is too nested.